# Solve System of Equations with Python

Tags: python, math, scipy

I am trying to use `fsolve` and python to solve a system of five equations, and cannot get the correct solution. In these equations we assume p_x = 1.

[image: Five Equations]

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

def equations(e):
x_i, x_j , y_i , y_j, p_y = e

ex_i = 200
ey_i = 16
ex_j = 300
ey_j = 12

du_idx = 1
du_idy = (15 - y_i)

du_jdx = 1
du_jdy = (25 - y_j)

return (du_idx-(du_idy/p_y), x_i+p_y*y_i-ex_i-p_y*ey_i, du_jdx-(du_jdy/p_y), x_i+x_j-ex_i-ex_j, y_i+y_j-ey_i-ey_j)

x_i, x_j , y_i , y_j, p_y = fsolve(equations, (250,250,15,15,6))

print equations((x_i, x_j , y_i , y_j, p_y))
```

Unfortunately, the output is `(3.8857805861880479e-15, -1.1368683772161603e-13, -2.4424906541753444e-15, 0.0, 0.0)`, and not the actual solution (242, 258, 9, 19, 6). We are given that ex_i = 200, ey_i = 16, ex_j = 300, and ey_j = 12.

Comment: Maybe you could try switching to the [root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root) function. It has more algorithms available to tinker with. Perhaps the hybr method used by fsolve is unstable.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should check the extra output of [fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html). The fourth output is the detailed message of why the solving failed.

Comment: I can't tell what you're solving for.  Which variables are the unknowns?   Is there a range on the subscripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `print equations((x_i, x_j , y_i , y_j, p_y))`

The output you print is the solution plugged into the equations, not the solution itself, right? No surprise you get a bunch of almost-zero numbers; that just confirms your variables satisfy the equations except for some tiny numeric noise.